# Upgraded to SDK 4.1 and can no longer install on device with OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation

Each time a new SDK came out, there has been the problem with the "Base SDK" which is really a "max SDK" and backward compatible. My project builds fine after adjusting the "Base SDK" in the Project Info.
But why do I get these messages on the console below the Target Info window when I change the "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 4.0?

```
"iOS 4.0 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.0. [4.0]" and 
"iOS 4.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.1. [4.1]"
```

The code did not change since the last successful install on iOS 4.0 under iOS 4.0 SDK.
The project builds without error, but the installation on the device (iOS 4.0) fails with

```
The Info.plist for application [path/to/app.app] specifies 
a minimum OS version of 4.1 which is too high to be installed
on [device].
```

But there is no mention of a minimum OS version in [project]-Info.plist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the iOS Deployment Target in both your Project and Target Build Settings?  If you only change the project setting, an old target setting will override it.

Comment: Yes, I did. After a restart of XCode it finally installed. The error messages persist, though.

Comment: It did work for Distribution. It did not work for Debug (and for my own device.) Double checked that iOS Deployment Target was set to 4.0 in both Project and Target Build Settings.

Comment: I noticed that the "iOS Deployment Target" in the Build Settings is only available for the Distribution Settings. When switching to Debug or Release, the option disappears.

Comment: The problem disappeared with version 4.2.