# will my app load on iOS 4.0 on their iphone? iOS 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings, target

using XCode 3.2.6, Base SDK iOS 4.3

I set iOS Deployment Target to iOS 3.0 in Target Info Build Settings and also in Project Info Build Settings

I get the following messages:

iOS 3.0 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.0. [3.0]

iOS 3.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.1. [3.1]

iOS 3.1.2 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.1.2. [3.1.2]

iOS 3.1.3 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.1.3. [3.1.3]

iOS 3.2 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.2. [3.2]

iOS 3.2.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.2.1. [3.2.1]

iOS 3.2.2 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 3.2.2. [3.2.2]

iOS 4.0 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.0. [4.0]

iOS 4.0.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.0.1. [4.0.1]

iOS 4.0.2 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.0.2. [4.0.2]

iOS 4.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.1. [4.1]

iOS 4.2 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.2. [4.2]

iOS 4.3 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.3. [4.3]
what do these messages mean? 
if someone has iOS 4.0, can they download my iphone app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgraded to SDK 4.1 and can no longer install on device with OS 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703357/upgraded-to-sdk-4-1-and-can-no-longer-install-on-device-with-os-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your project settings change the deployment target